# The media could not be loaded (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED)

Tags: javascript, apache, video, html5-video

**PROBLEM**

I'm trying to download a whole html page which contains video from some URL. Then I just printing what I've downloaded. On my `localhost` machine everything working fine. **BUT** when I try to run my code on Hosting server I'm getting this error:

```
VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) 
The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network 
failed or because the format is not supported. 
    code: 4
```

**QUESTION**

According to logic, if it is working on `localhost`, but **NOT** on Hosting server - is it a problem of apache configuration or something?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Check your mime type, according to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800990/video-js-contrib-hls-not-playing-hls-in-most-browsers-code4-media-err-src-no  Also, please post your code.

Comment: @MannfromReno, thank you for response. I'm just using function from this link to get data [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363022/get-url-content-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363022/get-url-content-php) . How should I define mime type ?

Answer (score 1):

According to logic, if it is working on localhost, but NOT on Hosting server
I've had the same problem.
Solution:

```
IIS->MIME Type->Add the desired video type
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Dears try this , its work for me on google chrome 
right click on the google chrome shortcut , copy this shortcut 
then right click the new google chrome shortcut and click properties -> shortcut and then add this at the end of the target text box

--disable-web-security --user-data-dir="c:/someFolderName"

for detail understanding fallow this link
https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2016/09/disable-same-origin-policy/

its work for me